# Formatting Highchart dateime time categories

Tags: highcharts, dateformatter

Can someone please tell me how do I specify format for categories in following code.
Why my xAxis categories in milliseconds are getting converted to "1970-01-01 00:00:00"

here is the link to my  [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaini/jj6jqyq8/1/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Categorized chart'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: [1496275200000,1498867200000,1501545600000,1504224000000],
        type : 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

$('#preview').html(chart.getCSV());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take idea from official [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/)

Your code will be like

```
xAxis: {
    //categories: [1496275200000,1498867200000,1501545600000,1504224000000],
    type : 'datetime'
},

series: [{
    data: [[1496275200000,29.9],[1498867200000,71.5],[1501545600000,106.4] , [1504224000000,129.2]]
}]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6a8koyv/) Demo

Comment: Thank a  lot, I will try to change my code as suggested